# Does libssl32 exist as a 64-bit version?

Tags: openssl, linker-errors, 32bit-64bit, ld

I'm trying to build something with Cargo and it says `ld: cannot find -lssl32`. I know this means it needs a library file, so I copy `libssl32.dll`, which I got from installing OpenSSL, to a directory where it looks. `cargo build` now complains that it's `skipping incompatible D:\foo\bar\libssl32.dll when searching for -lssl32`. That in turn should mean that it's a 32bit library but I'm building for a 64bit target, according to an answer on Stack Overflow.

Here's the thing: Every binary 64bit distribution of OpenSSL I've found seems to be lacking `libssl32` (They do contain `libeay32` which was another thing Cargo/ld complained about, but it stopped when I copied a 64bit version of that over).

After trying almost ten different sites, I see no 64bit versions of `libssl32.dll` at all. Why is this? Have I not looked hard enough, or is `libssl32` just not to be used when building for 64bit? And in that case, why is Cargo asking for it and how do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 0):

I did finally find that the newest 64bit version of OpenSSL on https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html did contain `libssl32.dll`. I also had to `cargo clean` before building to make sure it found it.